# How to list a Property in realm Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, realm

How to list a property in realm DB like `SELECT columnName FROM mytable`in SQL?

Here is my try:`let person = self.realm.objects(Person.self).filter("age")`

Comment: you can use `map` to get particular column data from model array

Comment: @Jaydeep how to use map in this case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can access a single **property** *(since Realm models are native objects, they have properties, not columns)* of all instances of your particular model class stored in Realm using `map`.

`filter`, as its name suggests can be used to only work on a subset of all instances of a certain type that all fulfilled the same condition (for example you can use filter to find all people whose age is above 18 by saying: `let adults = self.realm.objects(Person.self).filter("age > 18")`).

Get the `age` property of all instances of `Person` persisted in Realm using `map`:

```
let people = self.realm.objects(Person.self)
let ages = people.map{$0.age}
```

or in one line giving an Array as an output:

`let ages = Array(self.realm.objects(Person.self)).map{$0.age}`

Answer (score 2):

you can get list of records like this

```
let realmCities = try! Realm()
lazy var arrDefaultCities: Results<Cities> = { self.realmCities.objects(Cities.self).sorted(byKeyPath: "cityName", ascending: true) }()

func filterCities()
        {
            let statePredicate = NSPredicate(format: "stateId = %d", objState.stateId)
            arrDefaultCities = try! Realm().objects(Cities.self).filter(statePredicate).sorted(byKeyPath: "cityName", ascending: true)

            self.filterArrCities.removeAll()
            for objCities : Cities in arrDefaultCities{
                if objCities.cityName == APP_DELEGATE.currentCity
                {
                    self.objCity = objCities
                }
                self.filterArrCities.append(objCities.cityName)
            }
        }
```